# Ошибка в документации Nestjs?

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь первый раз использовать socket.io в Nest.
В документации Nestjs по Gateways написано следующее:
"The gateway is now listening, but we have not yet subscribed to any incoming messages. Let's create a handler that will subscribe to the events messages and respond to the user with the exact same data."

```
@SubscribeMessage('events')
handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: string): string {
  return data;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что здесь для ответа используется просто return и в документации Nest утверждают что таким образом мы отвечаем юзеру, т.е. юзер получит ответ.
Пытаюсь повторить этот код. Тестирую соединение в настольном приложении Postman. Запрос серверу приходит, но вот Postman не получает ничего в ответ. Пытался спрашивать в других местах. Люди говорят что нужно обязательно получать socket.id клиента и отвечать ему при помощи emit. Да, при использовании emit Postman получает ответ. Но меня продолжает мучать сомнение. Ну не может же быть, чтобы Nest, у которого так детально проработана документация, ошибся и не указал это в документации.
Знатоки, что скажете? Ошибка в документации Nest или я чего-то недопонимаю?

Answer (score 0):

в postman надо поставить галочку Ack, все правильно описано в доках.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]